# Does iPhone combine Push notification?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I observed in iPhone that,When an app receive too frequent notification and that app is in background,iPhone does not show banner for all notification,instead it shows banner with message " You have 6 new Connect notification." ( 6 is the push notification count and connect is the name of app.).Is this behaviour documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

As for your question of where it is stored, it is probably stored in the cache of the phone (which is cleared every so often) so you're not being monitored and watched as far as I know of. If you wish to turn off these notifications you can do so in the settings. Hope I answered your question!

Comment: Just want to know if iPhone skip banner for all notification , and shows only one banner with count message.